# Change projection from Unknown to given EPSG with GDAL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I've got a TIFF in projection (proj4: `+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-80 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`). Would like to convert it to `EPSG:3857`. ArcMap does it correctly, but GDAL does not. I tried gdalwarp:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-80 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co "COMPRESS=LZW"
```

Gdalwarp generates more or less empty output.

So I tried gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -projwin_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-80 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -a_srs EPSG:3857 -co "COMPRESS=LZW"
```

It gives some result, but it's wrong.
Both results are the same when doing them in Python.

ArcMap doesn't have a problem with that. Any ideas how to make it automatically with Python (not using ArcPy!)?

The results and input raster are here (around 1-3MB each):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NyXjYqSJI8KUSgA4AwTQbfLHCQhxILPG?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems that the problem appears only on Windows.

Comment: EPSG:3857 is not valid near the poles. The transformation works if you exclude the invalid area by setting the target extent parameter manually `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r near -of GTiff input.tif out.tif -te -180 -30 180 85 -te_srs epsg:4326`. After the GDAL improvement that is already done due to the ticket that you created the clipping is done automatically, but user must still be aware that the polar area gets lost in the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me with a simple:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r average -of GTiff input.tif out.tif
```

Your file already has a CRS set so no need to override it.

[image]

GDAL 3.8.1, released 2023/11/28

Comment: GDAL 3.8.2, released 2023/16/12 (freshly installed on fresh Windows) - got the same result as I attached in google drive. Just a black stripe. Same on GDAL 3.0.2. Are You doing it on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Weird! I am on Linux. Maybe there is a bad CRS in an auxiliary file overriding the one in the file? Can you try in a new directory with only the one single input file in it?

Comment: I did, on totally fresh OSGeo4W installation on fresh Windows 11. Still the same.

Comment: I guess it's a GDAL bug, but if You have any ideas on how to fix it, would be great. I've reported that issue on OSGeo github.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Could you link the issue here? Then future people can see if the problem was solved via GitHub.

Comment: Here's the issue: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/8996 . Thank You for trying to help anyway.